# Connecting to twitter using spring social twitter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-twitter

I am trying this example from [Spring IO Guides](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/)

which explains how to retrieve list of friends from twitter.

But when I click on Connect to twitter it does not connect to twitter.

I have my appId and secretId in properties file and it is in the classpath and I have read,write access to the app that I created on twitter.

[image]

What could be the problem

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34617539/2056394).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a callback URL in your twitterapp settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you application in twitter. Go to Settings tab and set the callback url.

**Callback URL**
`http://127.0.0.1:8080`

PS: You will have to change this url again to http://www.yourappurl.com when you move it to production.