# Why do i get a null connection to twitter with Spring Boot / Spring Social guide example?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I followed the instructions on the spring.io site:   http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/

And I'm not getting a connection.  The "findPrimaryConnection()" call is returning null.  I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown.  I did set the appId and appSecret in the .properties file.

Here is the controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Twitter twitter;

    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    @Inject
    public HelloController(Twitter twitter, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloTwitter(Model model) {

        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class) == null) {
            System.out.println("******** no connection yet: " + connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class));
            return "redirect:/connect/twitter";
        }
        System.out.println("******** connection found");
        model.addAttribute(twitter.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        CursoredList<TwitterProfile> friends = twitter.friendOperations().getFriends();
        model.addAttribute("friends", friends);

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="/connect/twitter" method="POST">
            <div class="formInfo">
                <p>You aren't connected to Twitter yet. Click the button to connect this application with your Twitter account.</p>
            </div>
            <p><button type="submit">Connect to Twitter</button></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception that's getting thrown?

Comment: There is no exception thrown, but here's the log anyway:   
2015-07-31 13:54:40.499  87372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializ
ing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-07-31 13:54:40.499   87372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Framework
Servlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-07-31 13:54:40.510   87372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Framework
Servlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
******** no connection yet: null

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the **Callback URL** in your Twitter's application settings - that should be said in Spring guides.

For instance, I have my app working with this callback url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback
```

[image]

It is explained right below the input field:

> **Callback URL:** Where should we return after successfully authenticating? OAuth 1.0a applications should explicitly specify their oauth_callback URL on the request token step, regardless of the value given here. To restrict your application from using callbacks, leave this field blank.

Comment: I filled up main web site URL but didn't set value of Callback URL that cause the problem for me. Thank you. It's working now.